# Multiprocessing - Process owns my computer

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I was just having a go with how to use the multiprocessing.Lock()

Working from the examples on:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

This example in fact:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def f(l, i):
    l.acquire()
    print 'hello world', i
    l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

I had this as my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
import datetime
import time
import random


def function(lock, i):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        time.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
        lock.acquire()
        print "%s says hello, World! at time: %s"  % (i,now)
        lock.release()



lock = Lock()
for i in range(2):
        Process(target=function,args=(lock,i)).start()
```

Running it in a shell, causes the computer to lock up at 100% cpu with dozens of python.exe's running in cmd. While all the time printing the message from either process 0 or one. Looking at the example I realised that I had missed the:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

So I added it fearing the cargo code Gods, and lone behold:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
import datetime
import time
import random


def function(lock, i):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
    lock.acquire()
    print "%s says hello, World! at time: %s"  % (i,now)
    lock.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = Lock()
    for i in range(2):
        Process(target=function,args=(lock,i)).start()
```

Prints:

```
1 says hello, World! at time: 2013-05-20 19:40:13.843000 
0 says hello, World! at time: 2013-05-20 19:40:13.843000
```

Edit thought it might be to do with the namespace so I tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
import datetime
import time
import random


def function(l, i):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
    l.acquire()
    print "%s says hello, World! at time: %s"  % (i,now), i
    l.release()



lock = Lock()
for i in range(2):
    Process(target=function,args=(lock,i)).start()
```

Still the same issue

Colour me confused?! Can anyone give an explanation to this?

Final Edit:

This is how I have finished my little example code now:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
import datetime
import time
import random
print "imports done"

def function(l, i):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
    l.acquire()
    print "%s says hello, World! at time: %s"  % (i,now)
    l.release()


def main():
    lock = Lock()
    for i in range(2):
        Process(target=function,args=(lock,i)).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which prints:

```
imports done
imports done
imports done
1 says hello, World! at time: 2013-05-20 23:26:41.015000 
0 says hello, World! at time: 2013-05-20 23:26:41.015000
```

Comment: What OS?  `multiprocessing` works differently on *NIX vs Windows.

Comment: On an XP box at the moment

Comment: Right after your import statements do `print 'imports done!'`.  My guess is that each new process imports its own copy of the module.  Which then recurses because it's not guarded by `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: that was a great way of demoing what was happening +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your script doesn't take over my Ubuntu computer, but it will take over a Windows computer.  Here's the explanation:

`multiprocessing` requires that the child processes be able to [`import __main__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction).  What happens on *NIX is that the child processes are created via `os.fork` which means that they're essentially cloned from the parent process with `__main__` already imported.  Importing it again does no harm.

On Windows, there is no [`os.fork`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork), so the children actually need to `import __main__` again.  But, when they `import __main__`, all of the code in that script gets executed which leads to the children spawing more children.  When you use the

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

clause, you prevent the infinite loop of children spawning children.

This is actually [documented to an extent](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) in the multiprocessing specification.

Comment: Thanks had just saw that foot note in the doc's when you posted the link, thanks for the answer!

Comment: children import the main module but probably not as `__main__` otherwise the guard `if __name__ == "__main__"` won't work. To avoid the fork bomb RuntimeError is raised on Windows in recent versions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your process run code in an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.  What's happening is that every subprocess is importing, and thus rerunning, your process creation loop, creating an infinite process creation loop (and thus killing your computer, as you've seen).  Wrapping the process start loop in an `if __name__ == '__main__'` will cause the process starting code to only run in the master process, not in all the children.